# How to disable a button in angular depending on changed informations received from JSON server

Tags: html, angular, button

I am using Nebular in my angular app.

What I am doing is that a get the informations in my JSON-server.

After that, I create a `nb-card` which contains all the informations that I received from the server in many nebular elements, like `nb-select`, `input`, `nb-checkbox` etc ...

That's the result :

[image]

As you can see I have a button `UPDATE`.
I want is this button to be disabled when the informations are not changing.

So the button has to be disabled when the page is loaded, but after at least one change ( for example I change the sport, or I unselect one checkbox ), the button should be clickable because I changed something.

The HTML :

```
<h1>PRICE RULES</h1>
<button nbButton class="but" status='info'>ADD</button><br><br>
<div *ngIf='priceRules'>
    <nb-card *ngFor='let pricerule of priceRules' style="float:left">
        <nb-card-header>{{ pricerule.id }}</nb-card-header>
        <nb-card-body>
            <nb-select style="float:left" [(selected)]='pricerule.activity' placeholder='Activity' status='info'>
                <nb-option value='Tennis'>Tennis</nb-option>
                <nb-option value='Badminton'>Badminton</nb-option>
                <nb-option value='Squash'>Squash</nb-option>
                <nb-option value='Paddle'>Paddle</nb-option>
            </nb-select>
            <nb-select style="float:right" [(selected)]="''+pricerule.duration" placeholder='Duration' status='info'>
                <nb-option value="45">45</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="60">60</nb-option>
                <nb-option value='90'>90</nb-option>
            </nb-select><br><br><br>
            <input type="text" nbInput status="info" shape="rectangle" placeholder="Price"/>
            <p style="float: right">{{ pricerule.currency}}</p><br><br>
            <div *ngFor="let day of pricerule.weekdays" >
                <nb-checkbox style="display: inline-block" status="success" value="true">
                    {{weekdays[day]}}
                </nb-checkbox><br>
            </div><br>
            <nb-card-footer>
                <button nbButton hero status="danger" (click)="delPriceRule()">DELETE</button>
                <button nbButton hero status="success" style="float:right">UPDATE</button>
            </nb-card-footer>
        </nb-card-body>
    </nb-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add [disabled]="boolValue" property binding to update button and set boolValue inside your component

Comment: Ok i did this, but how to change the value of the `boolValue` variable of the component to `false` when at least one information is changing ?

Comment: I added `(click)="change()"` on my `nb-checkbox` and added this method in my component :

Comment: ```change() {
    this.boolUpdate = false;
  }```

Comment: You can use reactive form valueschanges.subscribe function and change boolValue over there

Comment: how to do it with checkboxes ?